# List all days in a row VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of years (ex. 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021...)

How to list all the days of the year 2020?

So i would have: .Cells(2, 2) = 01/01/2020.... and so on until 31/12/2020 in the same row obviously

This is what my code looks like, but I think that I made it work only for the current year eg. 2019

```
Dim MyMounth As Long
Dim MounthDays As Long
Dim MounthDays2 As Long
Dim MounthDaysAppoggio As Long
Dim riga As Long
Dim numeri As Long
Dim mese As Long

MounthDaysAppoggio = 1
MounthDays = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), MounthDaysAppoggio + 1, 1) - 1)

mese = 1
riga = 2
numeri = 1

MounthDays2 = 0

For q = 1 To 12

For Row = 2 To MounthDays + 1

MounthDays2 = MounthDays2 + 1
Cells(4, riga).NumberFormat = 0
Cells(4, riga).Value = MounthDays2
Cells(4, riga).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(4, riga).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(4, riga).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium

riga = riga + 1

Next Row

MounthDays = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), MounthDaysAppoggio + 1, 1) - 1)

MounthDays2 = 0

Next q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple macro would let you choose the time periods aswell:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    'First day to the time period
    Dim FirstDay As Date
    FirstDay = DateSerial(2020, 1, 1)

    'last day to the time period
    Dim LastDay As Date
    LastDay = DateSerial(2020, 12, 31)

    'count the days between first and last day
    Dim Counter As Long
    Counter = DateDiff("d", FirstDay, LastDay)

    'Resize an array as large as the days you neeed
    ReDim arr(0 To Counter + 1) As Date

    'loop through the array with the DateSerial function adding 1 day to the first day of the period
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = DateSerial(2020, 1, 1 + i)
    Next i

    'Drop the array to your desired row
    Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for answering, sorry if I ask, but If I only have one input, only the year 2020. How could i achieve this?

Comment: @TheMite my code does the whole 2020, you just need to edit the  `FirstDay =....` and the `LastDay = ...` to suit your needs. Right now it does the year 2020.

Comment: yeah sorry Damian my question was wrong really sorry, it does 2020. I was asking about a list of years, like if the user chooses 2022 from a list, how can I obtain FirstDay and LastDay? I hope you understood me

Comment: I've found it out! Thanks Damian no more answers needed

Comment: @TheMite glad you found out how. You only needed to turn the 2020 into a variable and pass it through the procedure as parameter.